# Nullable<int> To Int Error

Tags: c#, nullable

I am getting this

> Nullable object must have a value.

error in this line:

```
   results.Test= installment.Test1.Value;
```

My 'Test' property looks like this:

```
 [DataMember]
 public int Test{ get; set; }
```

And my 'Test1' property looks like this in LINQ2SQL Designer:

```
public System.Nullable<int> Test1
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Test1;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._test1!= value))
            {
                this.OnTest1Changing(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Test1= value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Test1");
                this.OnTest1Changed();
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So is `Test1` actually assigned a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Test1` property is (still) `null`.  The underlying field `_Test1` will default to `null`.
You can use

```
results.Test = installment.Test1 ?? 0;
```

if `0` is an acceptable default value.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Was there a reason why you opted not to use GetValueOrDefault() for this?

Comment: @James: Every dev is different. We all know that.

Comment: @James: not specifically. We know the type (int) so we don't need an abstract way to get a default. And -1 could be a candidate as well.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Thanks. I was just curious. I didn't know if there was a benefit to using one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
results.Test = installment.Test1.GetValueOrDefault(-1); //set default value
```

Answer (score 0):

`installment.Test1.Value;` Assumes that `installment.Test1` actually has a value. The error you're getting, though, means that it doesn't, and that the property is actually `null`. Is that unexpected?

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` of `installment.Test1.Value` is a `null` and you try to assign it to non nullable `integer` type property `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `installment.Test1.Value` is null and cannot be assigned to `int`

Try

```
results.Test= installment.Test1 ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Test1.Value` will throw if `Test1.HasValue` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

if (installment.Test1.HasValue)
results.Test= installment.Test1.Value;

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the value property it needs to have a value that is not null. You can check to see if the property has a value by using the HasValue property.

```
var test = (Test1.HasValue) ? (int?)Test1.Value : null;
```

You can use the variable directly and not use Value property.

```
var testing = Test1;
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, because `results.Test` doesn't accept null values. I don't think this would work for nullable types either, actually. I think you'd need to do something like this: (int?)null;

Comment: If results.Test could not accept null values you would need to change the null to a 0 and remove the '(int?)'. It all depends on what results.Test accepts. If results.Test accepts null you would need to use '(int?)' because you need to set the int to nullable.